# node.js module export function structure

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to expose a service as a module in node. Once required like:

```
var MyService = require('../services/myservice');
```

I would like to be able to create an instance of the module and use its functions and properties like:

```
var myService = new MyService();
var data = myService.getData();
```

I am having problems structuring the module using exports. How should I setup the myservice.js code using exports?

```
//myservice.js    
module.exports = function(dependency){
   return {
      getData: function(){
         return 'The Data';
      },
      name: 'My Service'
   }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to instantiate an instance using:

```
var myService = new MyService();
```

> TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Hm, should work. Is that the only content of your files?

Comment: Like Joachim said, you syntax looks correct. Are you perhaps overriding that later in myservice.js? Or doing something else with MyService?

Comment: Look at the 'square' example from http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules , try to spot any differences your code might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say this is my Service.js module:

```
//Service.js
function Service(){}

Service.prototype.greet = function(){
    return "Hello World";
};


module.exports = Service;
```

Then in another module I can simply do:

```
//another.js
var Service = require('./Service');

var service = new Service();
console.log(service.greet()); //yields "Hello World"
```

That works for me. All you have to do is to export your `Service` constructor in the service module.

**--Edit--**

To address your question in the comments.

Whatever you export with `module.exports` is what `require` will give you back. If you export a function, then you get a function back:

```
//greet.js
module.exports = function(){
  return "Hello World";
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var greet = require('./greet');
console.log(greet()); //yields 'Hello World'
```

If you export an object, you get an object instance back:

```
//greeter.js
module.exports = {
    greet: function(){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var greeter = require('./greeter');
console.log(greeter.greet()); //yields 'Hello World'
```

And logically if you export a constructor then you get a constructor back, which was my original example.

So, if you use your approach, you get back a function, not a constructor, unless, of course, your exported function is actually your constructor. For instance:

```
//greeter.js
module.exports = function Greeter(){
    this.greet = function(){
        return 'Hello World';
    };
};
```

And then you can do the same thing I originally did:

```
var Greeter = require('./Greeter');
var greeter = new Greeter();
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin. Anyway I can wrap it all in a module.exports = function(){} like my example above?

Comment: Edwin: when I require the module; the variable instance it is assigned to comes back as undefined. The module does run and can debug it, but value returned is undefined using that syntax above for greeter.js. Can you verify the syntax?

Comment: It doesn't matter, all functions are constructors. The factory presented by the OP (function returning an object) doesn't care whether it is invoked with `new` or not.

Comment: @Chev I tested all examples before sharing them.